# Send mail on opening workbook: Run-time error 13

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to create a macro to send automated reminders.

I have two macros:

```vb
Sub Auto_Open()
    Dim vResp As Variant, dTime As Date
    vResp = MsgBox("Inviare email ora?", vbYesNo)
    If vResp = 6 Then 'YES
        Call EmailReminder
    ElseIf vResp = 7 Then 'NO
        dTime = CDate(InputBox("Send email at:", , Time + TimeValue("00:00:10")))
        Do Until Time = dTime 'OR = #8:00:00 AM#
            DoEvents
        Loop
        Call EmailReminder
    End If
End Sub
    
Sub EmailReminder()
    Dim oOL As Outlook.Application, oMail As Outlook.MailItem, oNS As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim oMapi As Outlook.MAPIFolder, oExpl As Outlook.Explorer
    Dim sBody As String, dDate As Date
    Dim oWS As Worksheet, r As Long, i As Long, sStart As String
    
    Set oWS = Foglio1
    Set oOL = New Outlook.Application
    Set oExpl = oOL.ActiveExplorer
    
    If TypeName(oExpl) = "Nothing" Then
        Set oNS = oOL.GetNamespace("MAPI")
        Set oMapi = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
        Set oExpl = oMapi.GetExplorer
    End If
    
    With oWS.Range("E1")
        r = .CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
        For i = 1 To r
            dDate = .Cells(i, 1)
            sBody = "Oggi è il compleanno di" & .Cells(i, 2) & dDate & .Cells(i, -4) & " " & .Cells(i, -3) & vbCrLf & "Facciamo i nostri auguri!"
            If Date = dDate Or Date = Int(dDate) Then ' Use INT to eliminate time info
                Set oMail = oOL.CreateItem(oIMailItem)
                With oMail
                    .Recipients.Add "umberto.roselli@openfiber.it" 'Indirizzo ricevente
                    .Subject = "Nuovo compleanno oggi:" & .Cells(i, -4) & " " & .Cells(i, -3) & .Body = sBody:  .Send
                End With
            End If
        Next i
    End With
    MsgBox "Messaggio email inviato correttamente!"
        
End Sub
```

I keep getting, however, on the second macro the error

> Run-Time 13: Type not matching

but it doesn't give me any indication where the error is.

Comment: Note that `.Subject = "Nuovo compleanno oggi:" & .Cells(i, -4) & " " & .Cells(i, -3) & .Body = sBody:  .Send` doesn't do what you intend. `.Body = sBody` should be a new line. Consider moving `.Send` to new line too, instead of using `:`.

Answer (score 0):

Fyi

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim OutApp, OutMail As Object
    Dim strto, strcc, strbcc, strsub, strbody As String
    
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    OutApp.Session.Logon
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    
    For i = 2 To Range("e65536").End(xlUp).Row
        If Cells(i, 8) <> "Y" Then
            If Cells(i, 5) - 7 < Date Then
                
                strto = Cells(i, 7).Value 'email address
                strsub = Cells(i, 1).Value & " " & Cells(i, 2).Value & " compleanno il " & Cells(i, 5).Value 'email subject
                strbody = "Il compleanno di " & Cells(i, 1).Value & " " & Cells(i, 2).Value & " sarà il " & Cells(i, 5).Value & vbNewLine 'email body
                
                With OutMail
                    .To = strto
                    .Subject = strsub
                    .Body = strbody
                    .Send
                   
                                    
                End With
                
                Cells(i, 8) = "Mail Sent " & Now()
                Cells(i, 9) = "Y"
                
            End If
        End If
    Next
    
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```